# How to combine inheritance with mock autospec in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

## The Problem

I'm looking for a way to properly Mock objects in my unit tests, but I'm having trouble getting `unittest.mock.create_autospec` or `unittest.mock.Mock` to do what I need. I think I need to use inheritance with a Mock object, but I'm having trouble making it work.

Image that I need to mock the classes in a 3rd party module that looks something like this (pretend the lines with `raise NotImplementedError` are external API calls I want to avoid in my unit tests):

```py
class FileStorageBucket():
    def __init__(self, bucketname: str) -> None:
        self.bucketname = bucketname

    def download(self, filename) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

    # ...lots more methods...


class FileStorageClient():
    def auth(self, username: str, password: str) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

    def get_bucket(self, bucketname: str) -> FileStorageBucket:
        raise NotImplementedError
        return FileStorageBucket(bucketname)

    # ...lots more methods...
```

And it might be used elsewhere in my application like this:

```py
client = FileStorageClient()
client.auth("me", "mypassword")
client.get_bucket("my-bucket").download("my-file.jpg")
```

If I replace `FileStorageClient` with a Mock object, I'd like to be able to find out if my unit tests run any code where:

- Methods that don't exist on either `FileStorageClient` or `FileStorageBucket` are called
- Methods that do exist on either `FileStorageClient` or `FileStorageBucket` are called with the wrong arguments

So, `client.get_bucket("foo").download()` should raise an exception that filename is a required argument for `.download()`.

## Things I've tried:

First, I tried using `create_autospec`. It is able to catch some types of errors:

```py
>>> MockClient = create_autospec(FileStorageClient)
>>> client = MockClient()
>>> client.auth(user_name="name", password="password")
TypeError: missing a required argument: 'username'
```

But, of course, because it doesn't know the return type that `get_bucket` should have it doesn't catch other types of errors:

```py
>>> MockClient = create_autospec(FileStorageClient)
>>> client = MockClient()
>>> client.get_bucket("foo").download(wrong_arg="foo")
<MagicMock name='mock.get_bucket().download()' id='4554265424'>
```

I thought I could solve this by creating classes that inherited from the `create_autospec` output:

```py
class MockStorageBucket(create_autospec(FileStorageBucket)):
    def path(self, filename) -> str:
        return f"/{self.bucketname}/{filename}"


class MockStorageClient(create_autospec(FileStorageClient)):
    def get_bucket(self, bucketname: str):
        bucket = MockStorageBucket()
        bucket.bucketname = bucketname
        return bucket
```

But it doesn't actually return a `MockStorageBucket` instance as expected:

```py
>>> client = MockStorageClient()
>>> client.get_bucket("foo").download(wrong_arg="foo")
<MagicMock name='mock.get_bucket().download()' id='4554265424'>
```

So then I tried inheriting from `Mock` and manually setting the "spec" in the init:

```py
class MockStorageBucket(Mock):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Pass `FileStorageBucket` as the "spec"
        super().__init__(FileStorageBucket, *args, **kwargs)

    def path(self, filename) -> str:
        return f"/{self.bucketname}/{filename}"


class MockStorageClient(Mock):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Pass `FileStorageClient` as the "spec"
        super().__init__(FileStorageClient, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_bucket(self, bucketname: str):
        bucket = MockStorageBucket()
        bucket.bucketname = bucketname
        return bucket
```

Now, the `get_bucket` method returns a `MockStorageBucket` instance as expected, and I am able to catch some errors, such as accessing attributes that don't exist:

```py
>>> client = MockStorageClient()
>>> client.get_bucket("my-bucket")
<__main__.FileStorageBucket at 0x10f7a0110>
>>> client.get_bucket("my-bucket").foobar
AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'foobar'
```

However, unlike the Mock instance created with `create_autospec` Mock instances with `Mock(spec=whatever)` don't appear to check that the correct arguments are passed to a function:

```
>>> client.auth(wrong_arg=1)
<__main__.FileStorageClient at 0x10dac5990>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set the `return_value` on your `get_bucket` method to be another mock with a different spec. You don't need to mess around with creating `MockStorageBucket` and `MockStorageClient`.

```py
mock_client = create_autospec(FileStorageClient, spec_set=True)
mock_bucket = create_autospec(FileStorageBucket, spec_set=True)
mock_client.get_bucket.return_value = mock_bucket

mock_client.get_bucket("my-bucket").download("my-file.jpg")
```

Comment: Best solution so far, the one thing it's missing from my attempt at inheritance is for the `client.get_bucket("my-bucket")` call to pass it's bucket name down to the `mock_bucket` instance that gets returned.

Comment: I might suggest that that might be taking things a little too far towards a [tautological test](https://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/12/20/tautological-tests/)

Comment: I don't think this falls into the tautological test  category, because I wouldn't use this code to test the `FileStorageClient`, I'd use it to test code that relies on `FileStorageClient`

Answer (score 0):

I think the full code I want is something like:

```py
def mock_client_factory() -> Mock:
    MockClient = create_autospec(FileStorageClient)

    def mock_bucket_factory(bucketname: str) -> Mock:
        MockBucket = create_autospec(FileStorageBucket)
        mock_bucket = MockBucket(bucketname=bucketname)
        mock_bucket.bucketname = bucketname
        return mock_bucket

    mock_client = MockClient()
    mock_client.get_bucket.side_effect = mock_bucket_factory
    return mock_client
```